# Displaying the type of variable in C++ code with cursor

Tags: c++

It has been difficult to see immediately the types of variables in C++ codes because they are defined using 'auto', 'template' and 'decltype'.
If you use IDE, you can detect the type after the compilation by being a cursor on the variable.
My question is, does an emacs package exist to achieve such a function?

Comment: I think your best bet will be irony-mode as suggested by @GuillaumePapin. With Function-Args disabled I still get mini-buffer descriptions of auto type variables - which were of type `auto` before compilation. So no, you cannot get this behaviour alone with Function-Args - my apologies. Will my check .emacs.d and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for sincere coping. I decided to use irony-mode as suggested by @GuillaumePapin. However, as he said, irony-mode is not enough to display the types of any variables in C++ codes. I think the demand of more powerful packages will be increasing.

Comment: I have looking for an option in `lsp-mode` with `clangd` language server. So far no success. `clangd` should "know everything". Anyone have an idea how to make it work there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode/), you can use `M-x irony-get-type RET`. This probably won't work for everything but it worked for the following snippet:

```cpp
int main()
{
   auto var = 1.0;
   return var;
}
```

Having the cursor on any of the two `var`, and calling `M-x irony-get-type RET`, returns: `double` in the minibuffer.

Comment: Helpful answer. Just to make this complete, I would add a key binding in my `.emacs` to get the type result without a need to type in the command each time. For example: 

`(global-set-key [C-f1] 'irony-get-type)`